# How to work with "example files" using testthat in R?

Tags: r, testing, read.table, testthat, write.table

I'm creating an R package using `testthat`. Many of the functions I am working with require a file as input and/or write a file to output.

Currently, my R package directory structure looks roughly like:

```
- R_package_name
    -/tests
        -/testthat.R
        -/testthat
            -/test_package.R
```

As an example, functions in this category would be `read.table()` and `write.table()`. The former reads in some file, the latter writes it.

What is the standard for creating "example files" for tests with `testthat` given the R package structure? I could create very small example files as inputs in the `tests`

Let's say I'm doing a test for `write.table()`:

```
test_that("check write.table", {

    df = data.frame( n = c(2, 3, 5), s = c("aa", "bb", "cc"), b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
    expect_identical(write.table(df), ???)

})
```

EDIT: Apparently mock's are possible in R:
https://rdrr.io/a/cran/testthat/man/with_mock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding was that the standard was to store data in the package as a `.RData` object in the \data folder of a given package, and that if you wanted to test reading in that data, you had to essentially call that data set, write a file, test reading it in, then cleanup.

However, looks like there may be a way to store raw data files, check out this link on handling [raw data](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-extdata). Here is another useful link on creating an R data package. [creating an R data package](http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/creating-an-r-data-package/)